# Saving an AnimationDrawable object to a file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animationdrawable, mediametadataretriever

I am very new to android development and trying to make an application that will convert a video to GIf using MediaMetadataRetriever and AnimationDrawable. I am able to display the GIF but I am not able to save the file. I want to know how I can save this GIF as a file or essentially an AnimationDrawable object to a file in JAVA.

Thanks

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmRetriever.setDataSource(MainActivity.this,result);

AnimationDrawable animatedGIF = new AnimationDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = mmRetriever.getFrameAtTime(n); #n is any integer
Drawable d = (Drawable) new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
animatedGIF.addFrame(d,200);

binding.imageView.setImageDrawable(animatedGIF);
animatedGIF.setOneShot(false);
animatedGIF.start();
```

Comment: you should post your current code, especially how do you "display the GIF". is it GIF in fact or just an `AnimationDrawable`? its very not the same...

Comment: @snachmsm added code for your reference. Thanks